# how to resize window to quarter screen width and height in slate

Tags: macos, mac, window-manager, slate

I'm using [slate](https://github.com/jigish/slate) as a window manager, and I would like to bind a certain key combo to automatically resize and position the window as follows

- window width and height will each be half the size of the screen
- the window will be positioned on exactly the top left corner of the screen

I tried this:

```
bind a:shift;cmd;alt push left bar-resize:screenSizeX/2;screenSizeY/2
```

but it's not recognizing that expression.. any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `move` command instead:

```
bind a:shift;cmd;alt move screenOriginX;screenOriginY screenSizeX/2;screenSizeY/2
```

Comment: excellent! works like a charm!

Comment: you seem like a true power user @Lauri.. here is a [follow up](http://superuser.com/questions/743214/how-to-make-four-windows-of-the-same-app-fill-four-quadrants-of-a-screen-using-s) question :)